# socket.io creacion dinamica de 'rooms'

Tags: socket.io

Estoy iniciando con la libreria de sockets.io y me gustaria poder poder tener 'rooms' creados dinamicamente, cuando cada cuarto tiene X numero de usuarios. Encontre un tutorial que deberia hacer precisamente esto: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_rooms.htm

El problema que tengo, es que supongo que es para una version anterior de socket y no doy con el como lograr hacerlo en la version 3. El error que me marca es:

```
if(io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms["room-"+roomno] && io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms["room-"+roomno].length > 1) roomno++;
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '/' of undefined
at Namespace.<anonymous> (C:\laragon33\www\cuarto\server.js:13:15)
at Namespace.emit (events.js:315:20)
at C:\laragon33\www\cuarto\node_modules\socket.io\dist\namespace.js:135:27
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

Alguna idea de como poder hacer que esto funcione? Gracias.